# OAuth consent screen not showing

Tags: oauth, google-oauth, google-signin

Recently implemented Google sign-in in my local dev. Everything works fine, except when I choose one of my Google accounts to log in, the consent screen does not show up. It does get authorized, as I can see my website in **Apps connected to your account** section of My Account.

I have already configured **OAuth consent screen** under Credentials section of APIs & Services console. Not sure why it's not showing up? I tried sending `approval_prompt=force` but it had no effect. Also tried `prompt=select_account+consent` which give me an error.

Some addititonal info:

- `authorization_url=https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth`
- `base_url=https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo`
- `access_token_url=https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token`

Comment: what scopes are you requesting?

Comment: @StevenSoneff Profile and email.

Comment: We don't require the consent screen anymore for profile / email address scopes. Selecting the account UI showing the profile and email info is sufficient

Comment: @StevenSoneff Thanks for your response! This helps.

Comment: In that case how to logout and login as different user ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**By design, the consent screen is not shown in the scenario described (account selection with profile/email scopes).**

I'm on the product team at Google and we removed the consent screen (the "Allow/Deny" screen showing the data being shared) in cases where only email and/or profile scopes are requested and the user explicitly selects their Google Account, since the account selection UI already shows the email and profile (name/picture) information that will be shared with the app.

Comment: I have added the following scopes : https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube

Still I can't see the consent screen and google keeps rejecting my app.